# python selenium StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На сайте dns-shop.ru при нажатии на выбор города появляется новое окно. Если сохранить все ссылки в массив, и перейти по 1, то сайт перезагружается для отображения товаров для этого города. Возвращаемся к окну, и при переходе на 2 ссылку (2 город) выдает ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of [object String] "67a6a865-c092-4278-9039-89a49a047d99" is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Знаю, что происходит из-за обновления, как можно сохранить следующую ссылку, либо полностью список?

```
window_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'select-city-modal modal in')]")
cities=window_div.find_element_by_class_name("cities")

cities_all=cities.find_elements_by_xpath(".//li[contains(@style,'list-item')]")

cities_all.pop(0)

for city in cities_all:
    city_a=city.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    city_a.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    select = driver.find_element_by_class_name("header-menu-city")  #ссылка на выбор города (новое окно)
    select.click()
```

Находил похожие вопросы, но там они сохраняли текущий объект с помощью lambda, а мне нужен следующий объект в списке
Пример:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
driver.get("http://www.github.com");
search_input = lambda: driver.find_element_by_name('q');
search_input().send_keys('hello world\n'); 
time.sleep(5);


search_input().send_keys('hello frank\n') // no stale element exception
```

Comment: А где здесь сохранение? Лямбда возвращает новый обьект, видимо.

Comment: @Alban, я не знаю, но они возвращались к этому элементу так

Comment: Это как обычная функция которая опять найдет элемент и вернёт его

Comment: @Alban а как в моем случае тогда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список объектов WebElement сохранять в большинстве случаев не имеет смысла, так как они теряют связь с элементами браузера после обновления страницы. Вообще, чтобы выработать оптимальную тактику, нужно знать вашу цель, но один из распространенных приемов - это создание генератора объектов. Чем-то похоже на пример с лямбдой, но еще и итерирует по элементам.

Данный вариант вам подойдет, если вы точно уверены, что при каждом открытии формы с выбором города, список один и тот же. Если города могут поменяться или даже порядок их отображения, то лучше каждый раз явно искать город по  названию.

Пример генератора:

```
def cities_all(driver, index=0):
    while True:
        all_elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.state-city-select ul.cities li.modal-row[style*=list-item] a')
        if index >= len(all_elem):
            break
        yield all_elem[index]
        index += 1


for city in cities_all(driver):
    city.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    select = driver.find_element_by_class_name("header-menu-city")  #ссылка на выбор города (новое окно)
    select.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cities=['Белогорск','Благовещенск','Зея']
for city in cities:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header-menu-city > a:nth-child(1)").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(city)
    q=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul[3]')
    print(q.text)
    q_list=q.find_elements_by_xpath('li/a/span')
    for idx,x in enumerate(q_list):
        print(idx,x.text)
        if x.text==city:
            q_list[idx].click()
            break

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: cities - список городов